# Как оставить только те категории(и его родителя) в которых есть записи?

Tags: laravel

Есть категории и подкатегории. Сделал использую SimpleTree.
Подкатегории могут иметь записи.(Записи отдельная модель)

Как оставить только те подкатегории и их родителей(категорий), которые имеют определенные записи?

Так всё правильно работают, но только подкатегории:

```
$query-> where( function ($query) use($type_radio) {
    $query->whereHas('record', function ($query) use($type_radio) { 
        $query->where('type', $type_radio);
    });
})->get();
```

Пробовал добавить orWhere и там перебирать с помощью метода map, но она почему то не изменяет запрос:

```
orWhere( function ($query) use($type_radio) { 
    $query->
        whereHas('record', function ($query) use($type_radio) { 
             $query->where('type', $type_radio);
         })->
        get()->map(function ($query ) { 
            $query = $query->parent()->get(); 
            Log::info($query ); 
            return $query;
        });
})
```

Comment: Формирование запроса останавливается и выполняется запрос, как только ты вызываешь метод get(). Метод map() уже работает с полученной коллекцией. А из модели подкатегории можно получить модель родительской категории?

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите отфильтровать категории, то нужно использовать join.
Как пример, использовать scope:

```
public function scopeCategories($query, $parentId)
    {
        return $query
            ->join('records', 'records.parent_id', 'categories.id')
            ->where('records.parent_id', $parentId)
    }
```